# SQL to match duplicates of multiple rows

Tags: sql

I've got a table setup something like this:

```
id | key | val
1  |  a  |  1
1  |  b  |  2
2  |  a  |  3
2  |  b  |  4
```

where each id can have many key/value pairs associated with it. I'm trying to write a query that finds cases where 2 id's have a duplicate set of key/value pairs in which I can specify what keys to look for. For example, in the table below:

```
id | key | val
1  |  a  |  1  <
1  |  b  |  2  <
1  |  c  |  9
2  |  a  |  3
2  |  b  |  4
3  |  a  |  1  <
3  |  b  |  2  <
3  |  c  |  5
```

The query would return the notated rows above if I specified a and b as the keys too look for. So far I have the below query:

```
select * 
  from MY_TABLE inner join 
         (select id 
            from MY_TABLE 
           where key = 'a' 
        group by val 
          having count(val) > 1) T1 on T1.val = MY_TABLE.val and MY_TABLE.key = 'a'
```

which works great if I'm only looking for duplicates based on a single key, but not for multiples. Does anyone have advice on how to modify the above query so that I can specify 2 keys instead of just 1?

**Edit: Things I've tried**

The query below comes close (from Max Sorin's answer):

```
select a.* 
  from MY_TABLE a inner join 
         (select key,val 
            from MY_TABLE 
           where key in ('a','b') 
        group by key,val 
          having count(val) > 1) b on b.val = a.val and b.key = a.key
```

but only gives me duplicates regardless of id. To be more specific, I've shown the difference below:

```
With below table       I want this      But this query gives me this
id | key | val        id | key | val        id | key | val
1  |  a  |  1         1  |  a  |  1         1  |  a  |  1 
1  |  b  |  2         1  |  b  |  2         1  |  b  |  2
1  |  c  |  9         3  |  a  |  1         3  |  a  |  1
2  |  a  |  3         3  |  b  |  2         3  |  b  |  2
2  |  b  |  4                               4  |  b  |  2
3  |  a  |  1                               5  |  a  |  1
3  |  b  |  2                               6  |  b  |  2
3  |  c  |  5
4  |  b  |  2
5  |  a  |  1
6  |  b  |  2
```

**Double Edit:**

I've been asked for a more specific example, so here it is. Let's say I want to find all objects who have the same values for keys "Name" and "Age". If I had the below table:

```
id | key  | value
1  | Name | 'John' <-- These rows
1  | Age  | '25'   <--
1  | Job  | 'Farmer'
2  | Name | 'Steve'
2  | Age  | '30'
3  | Name | 'John' <-- and these rows would be returned
3  | Age  | '25'   <--
3  | Job  | 'Plumber'
4  | Name | 'John' <-- But not either of these rows, because Age is different.
4  | Age  | '26'   <--
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Do you use NOSQL? Where is your primary? is the full table the primary?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm building/testing these queries against an MSSQL database, but it needs to run on MySQL and Oracle as well. If there isn't a DBMS-independent solution I can use separate queries though.

Comment: @inetphantom In this table, the full table is the primary. I prefer NoSQL and use it for personal projects but this is for work, so I can't change it unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test Data

```
CREATE TABLE #mytable(id INT, [key] VARCHAR(10), value VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO #mytable
        ( id, [key], value )
VALUES  
(1  ,'Name', 'John'),
(1  ,'Age', '25'),
(1  ,'c', '9'),
(2  ,'Name', 'Bob'),
(2  ,'Age', '4'),
(3  ,'Name', 'John'),
(3  ,'Age', '25'),
(3  ,'c', '5'),
(4  ,'Name', 'Samuel'),
(4  ,'Age', '25'),
(5  ,'Name', 'John'),
(5  ,'Age', '36')
```

Pivoted table will hold results of making a single row for each Name-Age pair:

```
CREATE TABLE #pivoted (id int, Name VARCHAR(50), Age VARCHAR(10)) 
INSERT INTO #pivoted
        ( id, Name, Age )

SELECT pv.id, pv.Name, pv.Age  
    FROM (SELECT id, [key], value
    FROM #mytable
    WHERE [key] IN ('Name', 'Age')) src

    PIVOT (MAX(value) FOR [Key] IN ([Name], [Age])) AS pv
```

Pivot function throws away unused keys, and turns the vertical list of values belonging to a single ID into columns.

We are looking for all the Rows in this new table that have the same Name-Age pair and not the same ID to locate duplicated people.

```
SELECT a.*
FROM #pivoted a
JOIN #pivoted b ON b.Age = a.Age AND b.Name = a.Name        
                AND b.id <> a.id

DROP TABLE #mytable
DROP TABLE #pivoted
```

I think that the schema is designed the way it is to allow the user to add dimensions to the data without adding columns to the table. If I wanted to store John's height I would simply add this row: `1, 'Height', '189cm'`

Comment: This gives me the same problem other things I've tried do: It returns all duplicates of a particular key/value pair regardless of id. I updated the question with my version of your query and the results I get.

Comment: Are IDs able to be duplicated? Should be also be grouping by ID?

Comment: There can be more than 1 key/value pair with a single id, yes. The id column is not unique. Check the edit, it makes this clearer

Comment: Can you describe the reasoning by which you are removing ids: 4, 5, 6 from your expected result? They do correspond to a duplicated `key` `value`, so why do we not want them?

Comment: Because the duplication I'm looking for isn't a single key/value pair, but a duplicated group of key/value pairs, based on id. To put it another way, I'm looking for each object (specified by id) where all of the specified keys have matching values. Does that make more sense?

Comment: I'm sorry, but it does not. Your phrasing of the question is confusing. if I have "1, 'A', 0" is that a duplicate (in your view) of "2, 'A', 0" ?

Comment: Yes, if the only key I'm checking is 'A'. But, if I'm checking 'A' and B', then there would need to be 2 more rows like "1, 'B', 3" and "2, 'B', 3" for id's 1 and 2 to be considered duplicates.

Comment: So the equality of rows A and B is dependent on the existence of rows C and D? I'm not sure how to react. This may be easier to explain conceptually if you assigned actual objects to the column values and explained what information you are trying to extract.

Comment: I added another example to the question, hopefully that helps. It's hard to convey because it doesn't make any sense to setup a sql database like this, but I inherited this database and don't have the luxury of changing the schema unfortunately.

Comment: @AdamWatson, I think I understand the schema now, and what you're trying to do. You want to identify all the ID that correspond to the same individual in this table. Is that correct?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this in your `JOIN` by joining the table to itself like so:

```
SELECT a.id, b.id, a.key, a.val
FROM MY_TABLE A
INNER JOIN MY_TABLE B on B.key = A.key and B.val = A.val and A.id <> B.id
```

Then you can add `WHERE B.key =` or `WHERE B.Key IN()` to narrow the results to your liking.

**Edit:**

Seeing your new structure, the above won't deliver what you are looking for.  One solution would be to use two subquerys, one for `name` and one for `age`:

```
SELECT *
FROM #mytable
WHERE [key] in ('name', 'age')
AND id in (
   SELECT a.id
   FROM #mytable a
   INNER JOIN #mytable B on B.[key] = A.[key] and B.value = A.value 
                        and a.[key] = 'name' and A.id <> B.id)
AND id in (
   SELECT a.id
   FROM #mytable a
   INNER JOIN #mytable B on B.[key] = A.[key] and B.value = A.value 
                        and a.[key] = 'age' and A.id <> B.id)
```